# SQL pass date into another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this kind of table which have varchar and int type only. I need to pass the date (parameter) from other table into this table. E.g : When i pass '2018-01-30' it will display from Jan column.
Is there a way to archieve this?

[image: Data]
[image: Data type]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display a different column based on the month of the date, that's possible eith a single query by combining the [elt()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_elt) and month() functions to achieve this:

```
select elt(month('2018-01-30'),jan, feb, mar, ..., dec) as mon from yourtable
```

`elt()` returns the Nth parameter based on the index provided in its first parameter. The `month()` function returns the number of the month in the date (e.g. january => 1).

If you want to display different number of columns based on the date, then that is not possible with a single query because the number of columns must be fixed in a query. In that case you need to write either a stored procedure that uses dynamic sql to generate the query or a piece of code in an external programming language that dynamically assembles and executes such a query.

Further notes:

1. The data stored in your columns seem to be numbers, yet you store them as strings. The `decimal` data type seems a lot more appropriate.
2. Consider changing your data structure and have a single month or year_month column plus a price column instead of the several month columns. Total and average can be calculated on the fly.

Comment: oh i see..im kinda new in sql..do u have any idea, or maybe to reconstruct the table so that it can receive the passing date?